# Installing phpDocumentor via PEAR, "command not found"

Tags: php, pear, phpdoc

I'm having trobule installing phpDocumentor via PEAR on a CentOS machine and I don't even know if this is pear or php related.

Here are the commands that I executed and their output:

```
# pear -v install phpdoc/phpDocumentor
## http://pastebin.com/2ijRG9KW

# /usr/local/bin/phpdoc
-bash: /usr/local/bin/phpdoc: No such file or directory

# tree -a -h /usr/local/lib/php/phpDocumentor/
## http://pastebin.com/NjynYKPL
```

I've included the tree command because I'm thinking something is not OK there...

At first glance, is this a PEAR or phpDocumentor issue?

## Edit

Tried

```
# whereis phpdoc
phpdoc: /usr/local/bin/phpdoc
```

But

```
# cd /usr/local/bin
# ls -l | grep -i phpdoc
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       48 Nov 23 21:46 phpdoc ->         /usr/local/lib/php/phpDocumentor2/bin/phpdoc.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     1039 Nov 24 21:31 .tmpphpdoc*
```

Guess what...

```
-bash: cd: /usr/local/lib/php/phpDocumentor2: No such file or directory
```

But there is a phpDocumentor folder (instead of phpDocumentor2) whose tree is available on this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NjynYKPL)

Comment: The error says that there is no phpdoc command in the /usr/local/bin/ directory. You'll have to find out where it is (probably somewhere in /usr/local/lib/php/phpDocumentor/). Try which phpdoc and/or where phpdoc

Comment: The only thing I have is an invalid link :\ (see edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same folder where I've executed pear install I found an error_log file:

> [23-Nov-2013 22:27:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of
>   33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in
>   /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Installer.php on line 580

Gotcha.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue and found there was no `phpdoc` link in my folder `/usr/local/bin`

To remedy the problem, I used `pear config-show` to allow me to view where the PEAR Bin directory is and then created a symbolic link that the `phpdoc` file in that location.

My PEAR Bin directory is set to: `/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.8/bin/`

My Local Bin directory is set to: `/usr/local/bin`

To create the link:

`ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.8/bin/phpdoc /usr/local/bin/phpdoc`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pear config-show` to see what directory it uses as its `bin_dir`, which is where the PEAR installer puts its "binaries".  I had thought that the main Linux distributions had preconfigured their PEAR setups to use `/usr/bin` as the right location, so you might try `/usr/bin/phpdoc`.  Granted, `/usr/bin` is almost always in your default PATH, so just trying `phpdoc` along should usually be sufficient.

That memory limit error from the PEAR installer means that the PEAR installer itself crashed while attempting to install phpDocumentor.  You'll need to edit your php.ini file to increase the value of the memory_limit parameter.  It looks like right now it's defaulted to a tiny 8MB.  I'd suggest at least 256MB unless this is a small/old computer.  You should then try a reinstall (`pear install --force phpdoc/phpdocumentor`).  I expect the `--force` will be necessary since PEAR might think it had installed it successfully already.  If `install` gives trouble, then try `update --force` instead.

Comment: I found out that actually there is a phpdoc "binary" in the bin_dir but it's an invalid link (see edits regarding the question)...

Comment: Right, but since the install crashed at a random point due to memory limit, there's no telling how many different ways it could be left screwed up :-)  Increase the memory_limit, or even disable it by setting it to -1, and then run my --force command(s).  That should get your installation done successfully.